# Toggle with image button with 2 layer xml. With Selector. I'm new and not sure how to proceed with it

Tags: java, xml, android-layout

My Activitymain.xml has this

```
    <ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/check"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="2"/>
```

My check.xml

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/auto"
      android:state_checked="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/manual"
      android:state_checked="false"/>
    </selector>
```

The toggling works, but I'm not sure how do I write the codes to do an if else condition to carry our certain actions.

My codes in java is something like this

```
    public void toggle(View view) {
        Button toggle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
        if (??? == "manual")) {
            toggle.
            button1.setText("Auto");
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            button2.setClickable(true);
        }
        else {
            button1.setText("Manual");
            button2.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My implementaion was something like this:

```
Switch toggle = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
boolean toggleflag =false;
if (isChecked) {
//some code
} else {
//some code
```

}